# PowerShell Script To build Visual Studio Project

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

Is there any powershell script exist to build visual studio project without open visual studio?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't even need power shell or visual studio. Just use the msbuild program installed with .Net. Usage example is like this:

```
msbuild DBMigration.csproj /p:Configuration=Debug
```

msbuild is located at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5` (or select your version)

There is also a powershell build system, https://github.com/JamesKovacs/psake

Comment: I've found msbuild in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin`!